# Access to Google Maps Geocoder

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, geocode

There are [geocoder differences](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences) between the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) and the [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps) geocoder.

Is there a way to access the Google Maps geocoder rather than that of the Geocoding API?

What prompts me to ask this is the fact that the [following query](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Department%20of%20Homeland%20Security):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Department%20of%20Homeland%20Security
```

yields the "Office of Homeland Security/Civil Defense, Aspinall Ave, Hagåtña, 96910, Guam."

However, searching for "Department of Homeland Security" on Google Maps yielded [this](https://www.google.com/maps/search/Department+of+Homeland+Security) instead, which is a better (for our use case) result than the one from the query to `maps.googleapis.com`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) is for translating **postal addresses** into geographic coordinates. "Department of Homeland Security" is not an address, it is at best a place.  To geolocate places, use the [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/) (but even that won't locate something as broad as "Department of Homeland Security")

Comment: Okay. Google Maps yields a better search result than the Geocoding API. Can you address the specific question above of "can we access the Google Maps place locator"?

Comment: You can only access Google's data through their APIs.  The [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/), is the API for retrieving place data from their place database.